# Only 1 log in at a time response code

Tags: http

I'm writing a system that only allows a user to be logged in from 1 client at the same time.

Thus: 
If the user is logged in on Phone 1 (using access token 1) and the user grabs Phone 2 to log in again (generating access token 2) the next any API on my system gets called an error code is returned.

Right now this error code will be 401.

Once the client detects a 401 response the user will get send back to the landing page and an alert will get shown telling the user that the account was accessed from another device.

Is 401 the correct error code to use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`401` error code means `Unauthorized`. In other words the same error will be returned if user did not access application yet and uses invalid credentials.

I would suggest you to use either `403 Forbidden`:

> 403 FORBIDDEN The server understood the request but refuses to
>   authorize it.

Or `409 Conflict`:

> 409 CONFLICT The request could not be completed due to a conflict with
>   the current state of the target resource. This code is used in
>   situations where the user might be able to resolve the conflict and
>   resubmit the request.

Comment: The user can indeed resolve the problem by logging in on Phone 1 again. So I guess 409 is the correct response code to use.

Comment: 409 is typically used to indicate conflicts in *modifying* state on the server. I'm not sure it's the best choice for this use case

Answer (score 0):

`401 Unauthorized` is typically used with HTTP basic authentication. If that's what you're using, it should be appropriate; otherwise, a generic `403 Forbidden` would be semantically more correct.
This, however, likely means that in order to identify a condition in which the user has another session open, you'll have to do something other than just look at the status code, as it should be used by other forbidden requests as well.